# How to get only records between two conditions in order with Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table items ranked with ranked-model. Some of these records have a boolean true.

The element with the boolean should act as the title of the section and the elements who ranked after are the element of the section, till the next boolean who represents a different section.

How can I make loops of each sessions (item with boolean true) and next items in order?

In the controller I added

```
@sections = Item.where(title: true).rank(:row_order)
```

Now I don't know how to get only the items after each sections and before the next one

Any help is very appreciated

thanks

Comment: What 2 conditions are you trying to query by ?

Comment: sections are items with title true, then I need to query items which are title false and ranked between 2 section (item with title true)

Comment: I suggest to perform database normalization first, 2 tables - `TitleItem` and `Item`, where item belongs to title_item. This even could be self joined table, where items has section_id key.

Comment: So you need to order Items where title true comes first and then add items where title false comes last in the order?

Comment: basically title_1, item_1, item_2, title_2, item_3 title_3, item_XXX

Comment: @MikDiet I thought about it, but I will make the app more complex, especially on the ordering items functionality.

Comment: Why would it make ordering harder? You would fetch title_items and iterate through them to display their items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch all items in order and use `slice_before` on that collection, using the boolean attribute. The ordering is done by ranked-model in your setup if I understand correctly.

For the sake of a runnable example I'll use a `Struct` instead of an `ActiveRecord` class.

```
Item = Struct.new(:name, :is_title)
items = [
    Item.new( 'title 1',   true  ),
    Item.new( 'item  1.1', false ),
    Item.new( 'item  1.2', false ),
    Item.new( 'item  1.3', false ),
    Item.new( 'item  1.4', false ),
    Item.new( 'item  1.5', false ),
    Item.new( 'item  1.6', false ),
    Item.new( 'title 2',   true  ),
    Item.new( 'title 3',   true  ),
    Item.new( 'item  3.1', false ),
    Item.new( 'title 4',   true  ),
    Item.new( 'item  4.1', false ),
    Item.new( 'item  4.2', false ),
    Item.new( 'item  4.3', false ),
]

items_per_chapter = items.slice_before{ |item| item.is_title }
items_per_chapter.each do |items|
  puts '----------'
  items.each do |item|
    puts item.name
  end
end
```

This writes the following to stdout:

```
----------
title 1
item  1.1
item  1.2
item  1.3
item  1.4
item  1.5
item  1.6
----------
title 2
----------
title 3
item  3.1
----------
title 4
item  4.1
item  4.2
item  4.3
```